# How to use a recaptcha custom theme with Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, recaptcha, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to customize the recaptcha inside my form, but I only get a javascript error. Can it be made, or do I have to modify the Flask-WTF code myself?

Comment: How did you try styling recaptcha? Did you see https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it that way but you can't control the code introduced by Flask-WTF without melding with it. I finally used the theme "white", not perfect but close enough.

Comment: Did you try change recaptcha css with own styles (with or without `!important`)?

Comment: The sanctioned way to style recaptcha is what you linked. The problem using Flask-WTF is with the code it generated itself, you can't control it. Please, do answer the question with the link you provided so I can accept your contribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example from bbenne10 almost does it except for one little detail: besides putting `theme: 'custom'` into your config you also must specify the `custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'`. Or whatever will be the id of container where the actual image will be injected and of course the container must be present in your html.

So the final config will look like this:

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'key'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'secret'
RECAPTCHA_OPTIONS = dict(
    theme='custom',
    custom_theme_widget='recaptcha_widget'
)
```

That said there is [a hardcoded template](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/flask_wtf/recaptcha/widgets.py#L10) that you can override with undocumented `RECAPTCHA_TEMPLATE` option. Put whatever you like in there and it will be used as base for all themes recaptcha supports.

One more option is to extend from `RecaptchaField` and make it use your custom `RecaptchaWidget` this way you can tell it to `flask.render_template()` with whatever template you like instead of hardcoding html into config.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this quite easily, actually. 
First, set (or extend) `RECAPTCHA_OPTIONS` to a dictionary containing `{'theme': 'custom'}` (and ensure you're doing `app.config.from_object(__name__)` or similar), and then ensure that your template contains all of the required DOM elements specified under the Custom Themeing section found [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization).

Example from a recent site:

```
# IN YOUR MAIN PYTHON FILE 
RECAPTCHA_OPTIONS = {'theme': 'custom'}
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = 'private_key'
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = 'public_key'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name)


# IN THE TEMPLATE (THIS USES TWITTERBOOTSTRAP'S FORM FORMATTING)
<div class='control-group' id='recaptcha_wrapper'>
<label class='control-label'>Enter the words above:</label>
<div class='controls'>
    <input type='text' id='recaptcha_response_field'></input>
    <a id="recaptcha_reload" class="btn" href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></a>
    <a class="btn recaptcha_only_if_image" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">
        <i title="Get an audio CAPTCHA" class="icon-headphones"></i></a>
    <a class="btn recaptcha_only_if_audio" href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">
        <i title="Get an image CAPTCHA" class="icon-picture"></i></a>
    <a class="btn" href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a>
    # This causes wtf-forms to drop in the js that populates the above elements
    {{ form.recaptcha() }}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours trying to get a custom design working I couldn't make it work. Flask-WTF outputs all the html and javascript code for the recaptcha to work. You can't change its behavior without editing the extension code itself.